# skip multiple characters while adding to a hashmap in for loops

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, hashmap

I have a string:

```
string[] = {"[","hey", "," , "how", ",", "are", ",", "you", "]" }
```

I'm writing this to a hashmap, I want the for loop to ignore all the commas.
I tried something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<map.size(); i++){
           if(string[i].equals(",")){
               break;
           }
           System.out.println(map.get(string[i]));
       }
```

I know it breaks after the first comma.

output is like : 
[
hey

I want the output to be:
hey
how
are
you

How to solve this?

How can I write something this: if(!string[i].equals(",") && !string[i].equals("[") && !string[i].equals("]"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `break`, you should use `continue`.

`continue` will skip the rest of the lines, and move to the next iteration of the loop. Hence, the rest of the data will be written in the hashmap.

---

Edit:

I guess that you want to skip the characters that are not letters. In that case, you can do:

```
if(!Character.isLetter(string[i].charAt(0))){
    continue;
}
```

This will skip all those characters which are not letters.

Comment: thanks!see the edit, how to write if statement to skip multiple chars?

Comment: it says isLetter  in the type Character is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @Nuwanda Oh yeah! I thought that it was a char. Now see it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `continue` instead of `break` operator.

Comment: see the edit, how to write if statement to skip multiple chars?

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not a big fan of `continue` and `break`. 
I think

```
for(int i = 0; i<map.size(); i++){
    if(!string[i].equals(",")){
        System.out.println(map.get(string[i]));
    }
}
```

is more linear.

Comment: How can I write something this:
if(!string[i].equals(",") && !string[i].equals("[") && !string[i].equals("]"))

Comment: You can have a List of undesired strings (e.g. undesired) and in the if clause test if undesired.contains(string[i])

Comment: it's just these three characters,i don't want to create another list for this

Comment: If you want to explicitely avoid those three characters you can use the condition you suggested if(!string[i].equals(",") && !string[i].equals("[") && !string[i].equals("]")), but I think for manteinance and future developments an undesired list is more useful